# VB.net Form ChartType not editable in code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to loop through all charts in a visual studio form, and change their type to line.

I'm trying to access the chartType property in the series object for a single chart before I implement the looping, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Chart1.Series.ChartType 'This part is not recognized by visual studios autocomplete
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm an electrical engineer with experience in mainly C, so I'm a little out of my element here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the loop? That'll help us work out how you're referencing each chart etc.

Comment: Series is a collection, so you'll need to specify which one you want to update Series(0) etc.

Comment: Please show more related code here. It will help others analyze your question.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, that actually was a very helpful comment, I was able to figure out how to manipulate series. Sorry I didn't add enough info, I will answer my post with a solution to the problem I had once I finish a complete code block.